# MVC4 & JQuery Mobile - Sometimes certain ActionLink buttons don't work at certain times until I refresh the page or open in a new tab

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to figure out why after I create a record in my app the same "Create New" button doesn't seem to work anymore until I either refresh the page, or I open the link in a new window.

1. I'll click "Create New" button at the top right:
   [image]
2. I'm taken to the Create view.  Then I'll fill out the form and click Create:
   [image]
3. Notice the new record in my list now:
   [image]
4. But see how I click the same Create New button, **it just stays highlighted blue** (this is the color it turns when you click on it)?  Nothing happens, but if I right click and open this link in a new tab, then the new tab will have the Create New form.  I can also do a programatic page reload via JavaScript which will solve this problem, but I don't want to do that.  Hovering over the link shows the correct route at the bottom the browser window, so I am not sure why this isn't working!!  Please help!!!
   [image]

Comment: Come on, no one has any idea???

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, same behavior.. it's very frustrating...

Comment: @Matt I found a solution.  I don't know if it's the right solution, but, in your BeginForm() call in your view, specify the Action and Controller, as well as an Html Attribute of "data_ajax = "false"".  This worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this one out on my own.  In my situation, when I was in my Index view looking at the list of items, I then clicked "Create" to create a new item.  Once I created it, it redirected me back to the Index view (as expected).  It was at this point that I couldn't any longer click the Create New button (as described above).

So, here's my solution.

In your Create view, specify in the BeginForm() call your Action and Controller, and add an Html Attribute called '`data_ajax = "false"`'.  That's all you need to do.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Fillers", FormMethod.Post, new { data_ajax = "false" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    @Html.Partial("_CreateOrEdit", Model)

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" data-ajax="false" />
    </p>
}
```

Now, when you create a new item and you get redirected back to the Index view, you are now able to click the Create New button again.  Keep in mind though that by doing this you will lose the cool animated rotating GIF that says "hey, something's processing, hang on".  I don't know of any other way around it at the moment.